# provider does not have permission to content when open intent camera

Tags: android, permission-denied, android-fileprovider

I have a basic :app module. and there is the :camera module.
In the camera module, I open the native camera using intent.
`MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`

but the camera doesn't work, as I get an error

```
UID 10388 does not have permission to content://com.example.android.provider/attachment_file/Android/media/com.example.android.dev/some_name.jpg [user 0]
```

---

here's mine provider AndroidManifest in app:

```
<provider
     android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
     android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
     android:exported="false"
     android:grantUriPermissions="true">
     <meta-data
         android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
         android:resource="@xml/file_path" />
 </provider>
```

if you change the `android:authorities` on `"com.example.android.provider"` then the camera works. But the app stops being installed on the phone due to other build variants installed

Answer (score 0):

**The Camera permission protected level is dangerous.**

so you have to ask the user for this permission in runtime.

here you can see the permissions level such as camera permission:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#CAMERA

And look in the Android developer training site examples how exactly you ask this permissions. The all information is their:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

The code should look like that:

```java
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        CONTEXT, Manifest.permission.REQUESTED_PERMISSION) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // You can use the API that requires the permission.
    performAction(...);
} else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(...)) {
    // In an educational UI, explain to the user why your app requires this
    // permission for a specific feature to behave as expected. In this UI,
    // include a "cancel" or "no thanks" button that allows the user to
    // continue using your app without granting the permission.
    showInContextUI(...);
} else {
    // You can directly ask for the permission.
    // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.
    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
            Manifest.permission.REQUESTED_PERMISSION);
}
```